# Flutter: Move to a new screen without using navigate

Tags: flutter

do you have any way to open new screen without using navigation, i want when i open a new screen, the fist stop and play continuous when i go back from the second screen,

i want when i open many creen like the image below, the D creen have a button the button will go back to the A creen, not open new tab A creen

I dont't want it like this:

[image]

I want this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (BuildContext context) => A(),
      ),
      (Route route) => false,
    );
```

Above line help you to achieve your requirement.

Replace A() With your destination class.

Comment: it work, thank
do you know any other way to do the same thing?

Comment: @BuuPham This one works nicely compare to others. You can read more about navigator here [Navigator](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html).

Answer (score 0):

There can be 2 ways to this:

1. You can use `Navigator.popUntil` since you have to go back to the first screen. This can only be used in case you know how many screens you want to pop.

```
count = 0;
Navigator.popUntil(context, (route) {
    return count++ == 2;
});
```

2. You can also use `Navigator.pushReplacementNamed` route. Check the link for more reference https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushReplacementNamed.html

```
Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, folder/A)
```

Comment: thank, do you know any other way to do the same thing without using navigation ?

Comment: without using navigator you cannot switch the screen. Though you can change the data on the screen as per activity done by the user. It will become unnecessary lengthy & complex coding.